# salesforce support

Tags: visualforce, administration, clickjacking

I want to disable clickjack protection. I have tried to log a case in salesforce support to turn it off (by default it is enabled and we can't change it).

Is there any way to log a case to turn-off this feature of salesforce?

Comment: You mean you can't turn it off in your dev org yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you a system administrator?

Also you need to have Site.com Publisher User field enabled on the user detail page
AND
Site administrator or designer role assigned at the site level

Comment: Thanks for your reply.yes,i am system administrator and using a developer account.

Comment: Have you got the Site.com Publisher User field enabled on the user detail page? Being a system administrator alone is not enough.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.yes, i have enabled it.still i can not turn it off.

Answer (score 1):

Infect for the above work i need production environment where i can log call to sales force support in-turn they will disable the click jack protection on my account.But it is security vulnerability.

Thanks for your comment and help....